# How to get data from postgresql json array field in an array

Tags: json, postgresql

Below is a json data in a column name meta and  table name layer.
Here  i  retrieve  data of 'pages' key by meta->'pages' but i have no idea how to get  'lable' key value which is an array element of 'fields' which is again in an array pages.

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"org_details",
   "action":"organisation.php",
   "lable":"Manage Organisation",
   "pages":[
      {
         "name":"Create Org",
         "lable":"Organisation Name",
         "fields":[
            {
               "id":11,
               "type":1,
               "subtype":1,
               "lable":"Organisation Name"
            },
            {
               "id":12,
               "type":2,
               "subtype":1,
               "lable":"Description",
               "mandatory":TRUE,
               "validations":{
                  "minl":2,
                  "maxl":60
               }
            },
            {
               "id":13,
               "type":3,
               "subtype":1,
               "lable":"Org. Type",
               "default value":1,
               "mandatory":TRUE,
               "choices":[
                  {
                     "lable":"OFSDP",
                     "value":1
                  },
                  {
                     "lable":"AGRICULTURE",
                     "value":2
                  },
                  {
                     "lable":"HUTICULTURE",
                     "value":3
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":14,
               "type":4,
               "lable":"checkbox",
               "default value":1
            },
            {
               "id":15,
               "type":5,
               "subtype":1,
               "lable":"Upload",
               "mandatory":TRUE
            },
            {
               "id":16,
               "type":6,
               "subtype":1,
               "lable":"GIS"
            },
            {
               "id":17,
               "type":7,
               "subtype":1,
               "lable":"Date"
            },
            {
               "id":18,
               "type":8,
               "lable":"Attachment"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Postgre documentation is some of the best i've seen. JSON page here. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: yes i read those but can't  get it.

Comment: My postgres doesn't accept `TRUE`, had to replace it with `"TRUE"` or `true`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way with `json_array_elements`:

(assuming that your table is `your_table` and json column name is `meta`)

```
select j.value->>'lable'
from your_table
join lateral json_array_elements(meta->'pages'->0->'fields') j
on true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can index an array by number:

```
select meta::jsonb->'pages'->0->'lable'
from   layer
```

To retrieve the "lables" of all organisations, create a table with [`jsonb_to_recordset`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
select  orgs.lable
from    layer
cross join
        jsonb_to_recordset(meta::jsonb->'pages') orgs(name text, lable text)
```

The second argument to `jsonb_to_recordset` defines the columns you are interested in.  Here I'm using `orgs(name text, lable text)` to make the name and lable available.

To get the value of a nested JSON dictionary, you can use a lateral join:

```
select  orgs.lable
,       fields.lable
from    layer
cross join
        jsonb_to_recordset(meta::jsonb->'pages')
            orgs(lable text, fields jsonb)
cross join
        jsonb_to_recordset(fields) fields(lable text)
```

[Working example at regtester.](http://rextester.com/HHWMJ25320)

Comment: want to retrieve values :  Organisation Name, Description, Org. Type, checkbox,  Upload, GIS, Date, Attachment

Comment: what do you mean by <your json here>

Comment: Replaced <your json here> with a select on the layer table

Answer (score 0):

```
select '[
{
            "item_type"       : "FEE"
            ,"item_id": 18
            , "item_status"     : "PENDING"
            , "description"          : "auto_pay"
}
]'::json->0->>'item_id' as item_id;

 item_id 
--------------
 18
```